# Laravel : calculate before inserting into DB

Tags: laravel, request

I have a form and before saving it in the DB is it possible to make a calculation?

I get a date of birth and want to make an account with the current year.

Example: 10-10-1990 and I want it to subtract from the current year.

1990 - 2021

```
$tabel->datenasc = $request->datenasc;
```

Comment: It is possible yes. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: The Laravel docs have tons of useful information. If you have a need and aren't sure how to do it, that's the first place to check. I find that more often than not it's built in. For instance, you're looking for [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)

Comment: I didn't know this function. I tried to do the calculation even before recording. From what I saw of the function I will have to create a function?

Comment: If I have to split the date because I only need the year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still do your calculations before inserting into **DB**

```
// if $request->datenasc == 10-10-1990
$current_year = date("Y");
list($day, $month, $year) = explode("-", $request->datenasc);
$year_diff = $current_year - $year;
```

you can now insert **$year_diff** in the database;

Comment: is it possible to mount the date again?
$newdate = $day - $month - $year_diff

Comment: yes, very possible

Comment: i trie this :  $datatest= date('2018 - $month - $day'); but in debug show this : "datenasc" => "2018 - $12Europe/Lisbon54 - $1854am"

Comment: No, that is not how to use **date()** method, refer to this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: its correct? $datatest= "2018-$month-$day";

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setYear` method from carbon library

```
$date = Carbon::parse("10-10-1990");

$dateWithCurrentYear =   $date->setYear(now()->format('Y'));
```